# Phonegap: how to play sound on android for a push notification

Tags: android, cordova, push-notification

I have a PhoneGap app with push notifications working on iOS and Android. The only problem I'm facing now for several hours is that on Android I only get a tiny badge on top of the screen for my push notification, whereas on iOS i get a sound, a notification on my lockscreen, notification center, etc, the full monty.

Is something like this possible on Android as well? Display a message on your lock screen or at least play a sound or vibrate when a push notification comes in? Is it something that needs to be configured in PhoneGap? Or do I need to add some JS to my app or PHP code to my server script?

Comment: I have the same problem

Answer (score 2):

You need use a plugin for cordova: https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-local-notifications